# java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes after creating JAR to OSGI bundle

Tags: java, security, osgi, aem, manifest.mf

I have converted a jar into OSGI bundle by extracting the jar, changing its MANIFEST.MF file and converting it to bundle using command jar cfm new-6.0.1.jar .\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF . But when I am trying to run the code I am getting error java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
Please provide your suggestions how to resolve this error.

Comment: the files in the jar are secured . by changing one of them the jar is invalid and therefor you get this error. you must re-sign the jar so the signature is valid again

Answer (score 0):

Does you deployment require signed jars? If not then you can simply remove all signature related attributes from the Manifest.

Comment: I tried doing the same but it does not work even after removing the signature file which I did by reomving the .SF and .DSA files.

Comment: What error do you get if you remove all signature related content from jar and Manifest?